# How to set uniqueness for multiple fields in ActiveRecord (Yii2)?

Tags: yii2

How to set uniqueness for multiple fields in ActiveRecord (Yii2)?
I have tried as written in manual

```
['a1', 'unique', 'targetAttribute' => ['a1', 'a2']]
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: You want each attribute to be unique indidually or the pair?

Comment: Also are both attributes in the same model?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

From docs:

```
// a1 needs to be unique
['a1', 'unique']
// a1 needs to be unique, but column a2 will be used to check the uniqueness of the a1 value
['a1', 'unique', 'targetAttribute' => 'a2']
// a1 and a2 need to be unique together, and they both will receive error message
[['a1', 'a2'], 'unique', 'targetAttribute' => ['a1', 'a2']]
// a1 and a2 need to be unique together, only a1 will receive error message
['a1', 'unique', 'targetAttribute' => ['a1', 'a2']]
// a1 needs to be unique by checking the uniqueness of both a2 and a3 (using a1 value)
['a1', 'unique', 'targetAttribute' => ['a2', 'a1' => 'a3']]
```

Comment: targetAttribute works for me.. attribute generates error.

Comment: I feel something could not be right over here. Docs says `$attributes` *Attributes to be validated by this validator*. And `$targetAttribute` *The name of the ActiveRecord attribute that should be used to validate the uniqueness* **of the current attribute value.** So, `$targetAttribute` should works fine (in fact, it is working fine for me). Even own Yii2 docs examples use `targetAttribute` ever.

Answer (score 6):

`targetAttribute` will be used **as of latest yii2** docs (2017)

```
['a1', 'unique', 'targetAttribute' => ['a1', 'a2']]
```

In this case field 'a1' will receive error message.

And the another case:

```
[['a1', 'a2'], 'unique', 'targetAttribute' => ['a1', 'a2']]
```

Now 'a1' and 'a2' attributes will receive error message if 'a1' and 'a2' are not unique together.

for custom message `comboNotUnique` will be used instead of `message`

```
[['a1', 'a2'], 'comboNotUnique' => 'Package Id already exist.', 'unique', 'attribute' => ['a1', 'a2']]
```

Comment: Good clarification, although `comboNotUnique` was deprecated in 2.0.10 and will be removed altogether in 2.1. `message` should be used going forward. ([reference](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-uniquevalidator.html#$comboNotUnique-detail))

Answer (score 1):

You can write your unique fields like below:

```
[['field1','field2'], 'unique']
```

Now, both, `field1` and `field2` should be unique.

As of `Yii2`'s official document:

> `targetAttribute`: the name of the attribute in `targetClass` that should be used to validate the uniqueness of the input value. If not set, it will use the name of the attribute currently being validated. **You may use an array to validate the uniqueness of multiple columns at the same time**.

Comment: Your solution is not intended for the same use case since it validates the fields uniqueness separately.